# How to remove all external links from database

Tags: database, wordpress, hyperlink

i have WordPress website with hundreads posts and i need remove all external links from this posts. But also new posts should have external links. So thats reason why i have to remove external links from database and not with script.

Any ideas how to do that?

Edit, i did this script what remove links from posts with ID 1 - 3568

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop' );

function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {

    if ( is_single(range(1, 3568)) ) {
      $content = preg_replace(array('"<a href(.*?)>"', '"</a>"'), array('',''), $content);
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Is possible add there something, what will send this data to database?

Comment: `sql` - find the column and update by regex

Comment: How exactly? What column and what regex?

Comment: `How exactly? What column and what regex? ` - this is up to u to find. Regarding regex there are plenty of docs (search by pattern). Maybe u want to enhance the question and provide more details

Comment: Lets say i have hundreads totally different external links. How to remove them all from database when they are different?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First need to identify the table and the column which hold the links.

There are 2 types of links : `site links` and `external links`.

Site links should be something like `http:\\example.com\anything_else`

 WP standard table for post is `wp_posts`, but for hiperlinks depends on the customization (can be a column in wp_post or maybe elsewhere. Here is up to u to find)

 Assume the table is `wp_posts` and the column is `links` then you need to find by pattern and update with nothing those columns.

 Mainly the pattern should be `start with :  http:\\example.com` (means links that will be keep as site links and not external)

 Translated to sql

```
update wp_posts 
set links = ''
where links not like 'http:\\example.com%'
```

Note: WP standard DB is MySql

Update:

```
function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
global $post;    
if ( is_single(range(1, 3568)) ) {
    $content = preg_replace(array('"<a href(.*?)>"', '"</a>"'), array('',''), $content);
    //find the post_id and set new content
    //wp standard way of working with post instead of direct sql
    //this will update each time each post, even the new one after display 
    //(if is in range, so for new one to remain unmodified just keep a lower range, 
    //up to last 100 posts)
    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['ID'] = $post->ID;
    $my_post['post_content'] = $content;
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}

return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i edit my question - is possible change links in database from this script?

Comment: See the update, but somehow you need to run a query to update value. Now you just hide from display those links, but not remove from db, Mainly need to do something similar with what i explain. If link is stored in db with `<a href...` then just replace in sql the pattern.

Comment: Looking further is to be understand that you need to alter the content and remove the links ?

Comment: Best solution would be remove links from posts in DB. Sadly i dont understand SQL.

Comment: Found something useful and may work, but better to do a db-backup first since it will update the db.

Comment: Mainly that is WP standard way of working with post, with "inbuild sql". But one more time, be sure to backup your db.Should work properly, but do not have now an env. to test.

Comment: `Best solution would be remove links from posts in DB` - depends of the environment. WP provide also various functions which perform DB operations (same thing as writing sql query). See update.